# Can ImagePickerController have the previewView when picked photo done?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view controller with UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate to pick photo.

I also want to make the same preview view when I picked photo done like the preview view when I taken photo done.

[image: make this preview view When I pick photo done]

Have any suggestion? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `UIImagePickerController` to show the preview screen when choosing a photo if you set `picker.allowsEditing` to true. Be aware though that this will allow users to crop and reposition their photo in both the photo library and camera source types.

Comment: Thanks your advice.